# putc needs stdout, vs puts

Tags: c, history, stdio

C history question here.  Why does the C function `putc` require a second parameter like

```
putc( 'c', stdout ) ;
```

While puts is oh so more convenient

```
puts( "a string" ) ;
```

There is a function in msvc++

```
putchar( 'c' ) ;
```

Which works the way one might expect `putc` to work.  I thought the second parameter of `putc` was to be able to direct `putc` to a file, but there is a function `fputc` for that.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I'm fairly sure it's really just a coincidence/accident. If you look through the entire <stdio.h> library there's a lot of redundancy, strange naming, and general lack of standard.

Comment: `putchar` is 100% standard and always has been. It's not MSVC-specific.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
int putc ( int character, FILE * stream );
```

Writes a character to the stream and advances the position indicator.
So it is a more generic function than `putchar`
Other functions can be based on this e.g.

```
#define putchar(c) putc((c),stdout)
```

According to Kernighan's book `putc` is equivalent with `fputc` but `putc` could be implemented as a macro and putc *may have to evaluate its stream argument more than once*.
I have read that supposedly that both exist for backward compatibility, but not sure if this is valid

Answer (score 2):

It is so you have the option to output to a different stream such as a file.

`fputc` and `putc` are defined largely the same, except that `putc` may be a macro which evaluates the stream paramter more than once. `fputc` only evaluates the stream parameter once.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between putc and fputc is that by using putc, you risk running the macro version which is inherently unsafe because it may have to evaluate its stream argument more than once. This causes complications that most people aren't aware of and thus do not watch out for, so fputc is better to use. fputc's macro does not have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

`putchar()` isn't just in MSVC - it's a standard C function (well, macro really).